# Blur part of an image

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I want to blur part of a image. I could blur the full image blurred using CIFilter ("CIGaussianBlur") but not a part of it.

For example: I want to blur the image in a small circular or square shape wherever the user taps the image.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You know how to blur a whole image so you can draw the touched part of the image into a new image, blur that, and then draw it over the original at the touched point.

Comment: And crop it to a circular shape.

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches. One would be to create a `CIImage` greyscale mask image with the shape you want, a blurred `CIImage` (using `CIGaussianBlur`), and then use `CIBlendWithMask` to blend them together.

The inputs of `CIBlendWithMask` are the input image (the blurred image), the input background image (the unblurred image), and the mask image (the shape you want). The output is the image you desire.